CPU choosing for Anylogic
I am considering buying a new laptop to replace my old one and I need to run Anylogic on it. So can anylogic be run on ryzen platform? Or is it just for intel processors only?
I checked on the system requirements page on anylogic and it didn't mention any about CPU platfroms
Link: https://anylogic.help/anylogic/ui/system-requirements.html

Ryzen is 100% fine, running it on Threadripper here. I can run 48 parallel replications, no problem.
If you can run Windows/MacOS, you can run AnyLogic
